# Competing edits?

Tags: discussion

As there was already an accepted answer for this question ([Android reshapes dice in casino](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49153/android-reshapes-dice-in-casino/49156#49156)), I edited Zimul8's accepted answer to add some additional info and some video links.

A few minutes afterward, he removed the changes I made.

I still think the information is relevant and useful. Is there a protocol for competing edits or should I just post a new answer even though his is already accepted?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### The general case

The commonly accepted protocol on SE sites is: the author of a post has the final say in edits. So if the author does not want that info there, don't put it there or edit-war with them to force it to be there.

There are exceptions to this, such as when a question's author is resisting badly needed clean-up, but such cases should probably be handled and enforced by a mod. This is not one of those situations.

#### This specific case

It's pretty reasonable for that author to reject your edit. You should have posted your own answer instead.

In your view, you're just adding helpful information, sure. And it is helpful information.

But in [both revisions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/49156/revisions) you're replacing the *entire answer* with a completely different one! That is ***not*** what editing is for. If this were an edit in the suggested edit queue, I'd reject it for this reason:

> This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost.

If you want to completely rewrite someone's answer into your own answer, just post your own answer. There is no reason not to. This is still the case even if it's the accepted answer, which should have no bearing on whether you edit or post your own answer. Your edits in this case are bordering on vandalism, except that it's the *good* variety of completely destroying someone else's answer. (But you're still completely destroying someone else's answer.)

In less major cases, if you want to add substantial amounts of information and they reject it, just post your own answer.

Comment: I completely agree with this. I decided to avoid the edit-war by asking the poster if he was happy with me taking an axe to his answer and leaving him a complete copy of the text if he decided to resist the edit.

Comment: You don't need to leave him an original; it is already in the history where it can be rolled back.

Comment: Fair enough. If he undoes it (and he's got every right to do so if he wants) I'll repost it as a separate answer.

Comment: (Posting here just for completeness) In this particular case, there was actually no intent to undo @Richard 's changes. I apparently crossed edits with him. Once he flagged me and noted the deletion, I invited him to reinsert them, as the video links were pertinent and, I thought, interesting. Good answer here though, Jonathan. We probably should reserve edits for corrections, and use separate answers to augment with additional material, both to avoid conflicts over posting style and in truth to give posts like Richard's an opportunity to glean their deserved upvotes.

Comment: Yes - or deserved downvotes. Adding a little extra material is fine, but this was far more than a little. It's good to hear it was OK though.

Comment: Fully agreed. My original edit wasn't actually that big a change but the subsequent one was.   In hindsight a new answer would have been more appropriate than editing, even if there was already an accepted answer.